# Are "free products" just coproducts in categories admitting presentations of objects (generators and relators)?

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra, universal-property, free-product

For groups, the "free product" can be taken "generator-wise" and "relator-wise" as done here:

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+product+of+groups

It is also the case that the "free product" is the coproduct in the category of groups. For other (algebraic, and hence concrete) categories, we can find free objects and write down arbitrary objects in terms of generators and relators of a presentation that specifies them (monoids, quandles, rings, etc.). These categories have somewhat different coproducts, however (coproduct in Ab is *not* disjoint union, but would, in some sense, be equivalent to some general coproduct were we to instinctively include the commutator as a relator).

I am asking "does this discrepancy matter"? Or is it the case that, whenever we have free objects and coequalizers (and hence coproducts) (as we do in algebraic categories) we will be able to use these coproducts as though they were the "free product" of groups ("generator-wise" and "relator-wise")? Do we simply have to keep track of "category specific relations", like needing to include the commutator for abelian groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question's not crystal clear, but a relevant point is that you can always give the coproduct of two algebraic gadgets given by presentations $A=\langle a_i|r_i\rangle,B=\langle b_j|s_j\rangle$ by "juxtaposing presentations", to get $\langle a_i,b_j|r_i,s_j\rangle$. Thus the coproduct is always the free gadget generated by generators of $A$ and $B$ subject to the relations coming from $A$ and from $B$. Of course in different algebraic theories, there are different relations that always hold, but of course there are also different *operations*! All this is probably best thought of as being encoded in the "free gadget on some generators" construction, as well as in the coequalizer determined by the relations.

Comment: Ok excellent, this is basically the answer to my question! Do you have a proof of this though? I imagine it is due to the universal properties of free objects and coequalizers, but I am not sure what else. Also, would you agree that such a thing can then be done in any algebraic category? https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+category

Comment: @ASillyGuy Well, a map from a structure with presentation $\langle a_i|r_i\rangle$ is uniquely determined by a choice of image of each generator $a_i$ which respects the relations $r_i$. So a map from $\langle a_i,b_j|r_i,s_j\rangle$ is given by a choice of images of $a_i$ and $b_j$ subject to $r_i$ and $s_j$, which is precisely the data of a map from $A$ and a map from $B$. This gives an apparently trivial construction of coproducts in such a category, but it's hiding nontrivial work in constructing the free object on some generators subject to some relations...

Comment: I agree that this works in any algebraic category in the sense at your link.

Comment: Thanks very much, both for your concise answer and honest interpretation.

Comment: I just thought of another related question, but perhaps it was best suited to comments- is it also fair to say that $B$ is still "embedded" into our new presentation, $\langle a_i , b_j \vert r_i , s_j \rangle$?